# How can i get input data from a form in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, server-side, web-development-server

Working on a weather application in node.js But when i tried to get the input value through `document.getElementById`  to show weather about a specific location it is showing error
i have a file in my views folder where i provide JavaScript file using script tag but even then I am getting error.

error is given below:

`GET http://localhost:3000/js/JavaScript.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the fact that you are not serving a static files in your nodejs server. If you are using express server in your application you have to give the below code in main server js file
`app.use(express.static('public'))` here public means the folder where you have html, js folder, css folder

Comment: you can only use document.getElementById in frontend javascript file. To send the input data to node js either you can use form action to submit the input to a route  or send an ajax request to a route from the frontend and fetch it in the node js backend through the route

Comment: thank you again , the solution you provided earlier  worked.